change row color in datagridview only works in some code
Thank-you to all who have responded to this somewhat common question.  My twist on this issue is that in part of my application I was able to change the color of a row while building the unbound datagrid using the following code:
iRowNo = GridView.Rows.Count -1;

GridView.Rows[iRowNo].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(dgvR, dgvG, dgvB);

I have multiple tabs in my application and this code working in all tabs.  I also have other forms I load and build datagrids.  The above code will not work (no error but does not display the changed color in the loaded forms.  However after the datagrid is built I use this loop to change individual row colors.
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value) == " ")
{
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(cpldgvR, cpldgvG, cpldgvB);
}

Any ideas why the first code won't work in a different form?

Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value) == "" empty string doesn't need extra space
